# Google Play Game Services - Real Time Multiplayer - How to get the delay

Tags: mobile, multiplayer, google-play-games

I am using google play game services – real time multiplayer API to add multiplayer feature to my mobile games. The engine I am using is Unity3D, but my question does not have to do with Unity (I believe so) so it is not important.

What I would like to know is the delay of the messages that are received over the internet to make my games smooth and synchronized.

I know that in other APIs like Photon you can easily find the delay of the message that is being received but I don’t seem to find it on google play game services API.

**Is there any way to know the delay of the received messages on google play game services API?**

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0):

Determining the latency of the messages is a bit complex in the case of Google Real Time multiplayer APIs since the connections are peer to peer, so most of the data travels directly from one player to the other. (see for details: https://developers.google.com/games/services/common/concepts/realtimeMultiplayer#messaging)

The short answer is you can estimate it yourself, by adding sequence numbers to the messages, and then exchange the time difference each client experienced between the messages.  I recommend measuring several messages, and sizes, and not have too much memory since conditions will change.  Something like the average time between each message for 30-100 messages and then plan for the slowest link.

To make a good real-time game, you really should assume the latency is variable (sometimes it is low, others high), and it is always longer than you want :)

You might want to checkout https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/58450/mobile-multiplayer-games-and-coping-with-high-latency which has a good discussion on how to handle this situation.